# Selecting value from dropdown-box is not possible with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I try to select the value "Ukrainian Division" in the dropdown box of the following site:

https://www.cyberarena.live/schedule-efootball

with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
  WAIT = 3
  options = Options()
  options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')                               
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  link = f"https://www.cyberarena.live/schedule-efootball" 
  driver.get (link)  

  time.sleep(WAIT)     
  select = Select(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//select")[1])
  select.select_by_visible_text('Ukrainian Division')    
  # select.select_by_value("1")
  input("Press!")  
  driver.quit()
```

But unfortunately, nothing happens - the options are not selected with this code.
I also tried it with select_by_value with this line

```
select.select_by_value("1")
```

instead of

```
select.select_by_visible_text('Ukrainian Division')
```

but this doesn´t work either.

How can I select this option from the dropdown box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried ypur code and I also could not use Selenium Select object there. I don't know why. But we still can do that directly, with regular Selenium commands.
The following code is working:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

url = 'https://www.cyberarena.live/schedule-efootball'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[contains(.,'Division')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Ukrainian')]"))).click()
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot again - works great.
Only for clarificaton - with this `//select[contains(.,'Division')]` xpath-selector you get the select-element where some of their childs have "Division" in it. Correct?

Comment: Right. As you already know there are 2 select elements there, so I used some child text to locate it instead of 2 index you used. Indexation in normally less stable than internal child property. And you are welcome again :)